# What's the best way to save KML in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, maps, kml, area, region

I have a few maps with certain areas (zones) which I'll want to capture in KML. Within those areas I need to pinpoint addresses.

How do I save those maps with its values as efficient as possible to query them later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use MySQL spatial extensions.

Take a look at [GIS and Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html) and to [GIS on MySQL](http://mysqlgis.com/)